# What would be the correct way of writing 10⁻³⁶ second into words?

Tags: numbers

I tried Google, and I couldn't find the answer, so I have to have ask this question here. Is this correct?

> one millionth of a billionth of a trillionth of a second.

I can write one 'undecillionth' of a second, but I don't feel that many people would imagine the weight of the said term like they can with millionth to trillionth?

Comment: What you have reads okay to me, assuming the information is correct.

Comment: I guess only Carl Sagan said things like "a billionth of a trilliionth" in a vain attempt to seem more intelligible.

Comment: When speaking to people who might not be familiar with exponentiation, it would be *far* more considerate of your audience to say something like ***One part in ten followed by 35 zeroes***](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C2CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&source=hp&ei=MsQnXNK_NO6KlwTNlaWQDA&q=%22part+in+ten+followed+by%22&btnK=Google+Search&oq=%22part+in+ten+followed+by%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2041.8807..11029...0.0..0.186.2870.12j14......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0j35i39j0i7i30j0i7i10i30j0i67j0i10j0i8i7i30j0i5i30j33i10.Efh9iy5n1ZQ)

Comment: ...where of course you could save *yourself* a bit of maths with [***One part in one followed by 36 zeroes***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22part+in+one+followed+by%22), but there aren't so many written instances of that version, simply because it's less "accessible" to the non-mathematically-minded.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, was an attempt to seem more intelligible the reason for such turns of phrase? I thought that the reason was to create a vague impression that the number  is awesomely small (or large, as the case may be) rather than just stating the number in a matter-of-fact way.

Comment: I don't think anyone can imagine a quantity that small. You can think up imaginative ways: as many as there are stars in the galaxy or cells in the human body or atoms in a pint of milk.

Answer (score 1):

Note, "negative" as used in this answer is interchangeable with "minus". Thanks to a number of commenters pointing this out, NGram Viewer and Google search both show "minus" as being more frequent than "negative". "Negative" may be more common in formal use.

Exponentiation such as you've shown is usually said, in your example either:

> Ten raised to the power of negative 36

or

> Ten to the power of negative 36

or

> Negative 36th power of 10 (less common)

or

> Ten to the negative 36th power

or more casually as:

> Ten to the negative 36th

Notice that in some cases we usually use the cardinal number (36) whereas in other cases we use the ordinal number (36th) when referring to the exponent. Although what I've listed are the more common ways, the cardinal and ordinal forms aren't absolutely universal. For example, you may hear:

> 10 to the negative 36

However, in my opinion this is much less common.

_

> The exponent is usually shown as a superscript to the right of the
>   base. In that case, b^n is called "b raised to the n-th power", "b
>   raised to the power of n", or "the n-th power of b".
>  [Wikipedia:
>   Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)

Notice how it's said in this [Khan Academy video](https://youtu.be/trdbaV4TaAo?t=417), it's said in the shorter way I described, ie., he says ten to the twenty-third.

Specifically in your case of seconds, it would be said:

Ten to the negative 36th seconds
or
Ten raised to the power of negative 36 seconds
or
Ten to the power of negative 36 seconds
or
36th power of 10 seconds (somewhat less common in my opinion, I don't recommend this)

Finally, about the word "undecillion" or "undecillionth", I would advise against using that unless comprehension is not important. Firstly, it's an uncommon word. Secondly, as shown by the dictionary definition below, it can be two different numbers, I assume as a result of the differences between the short and long scales which (historically) separated Europe and the US.

> undecillion
>  a cardinal number represented in the U.S. by 1
>   followed by 36 zeros, and in Great Britain by 1 followed by 66 zeros.
>   
>  [Random House Unabridged Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/undecillion)

Comment: Thank you so much, you took out some of your valuable time for 'me' to answer my query. You're awesome!

Comment: We often say "ten to the minus thirty-six" for that amount where I come from (UK).

Comment: @Jeeped Are you saying that my answer should have been 1E-36 or that my answer misleadingly implies that 10^-36 is scientific notation? In other words that 10^-36 is not scientific notation but (1 x 10^-36) is? If so, I'll change that part.

Comment: That's the way I understand it. In scientific notation, the first number is between 1 and 9.999. Iit's 1x10^36 or 1E-36. (sorry about the -37 eatlier, I was on the wrong track)

Comment: @Jeeped Haha, OK. I've purged my answer of "scientific notation" and instead replaced it with simple "exponentiation", which it is as far as I know. Thanks for pointing out the strict definition of scientific notation, my mistake was in assuming  that 10^-36 was scientific notation, whereas by technical definition it isn't, I'm pretty sure. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Remember that the ambiguity of _undecillionth_ also applies to _millionth of a billionth of a trillionth_ (= a millionth of a milliardth of a billionth).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *Ten to the minus thirty-six* sounds a lot more natural to me too. (I'm Canadian, but I don't know if this has anything to do with regionalism.) Using the words *power* and *negative* seems unnecessarily long and formal. However, I suppose this could be a case where writing it and speaking it are distinct things. As well as the level of formality you want to achieve.

Comment: There are almost twice as many written instances of [Ten to the power of **minus** (X)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Ten+to+the+power+of+minus%22) as there are of [Ten to the power of **negative** (N)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Ten+to+the+power+of+negative%22).

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the information. That's been one Briton and a Canadian who've said "to the negative 36" sounds more natural than "to the negative 36th". I've added a note about this.

Comment: @Zebrafish: No - what we're saying is it's more natural to use ***minus***, not ***negative***.

Comment: *To the* ***minus***. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford: (Aw, *snap!* ;)

Comment: @Zebrafish: It's a long answer, but I don't think you really addressed the point made in my comment to the question itself. Assuming we're talking about how best to use ***natural language*** to reference abstract ***mathematical*** concepts, I'd say it's better to discard all references to exponentiation itself - and but since it's a ***negative*** exponent, that can more easily be grasped by less numerate people with ***One part in [big number]*** rather than ***zero point [big number of zeroes] one***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh dear. First I revised the answer because I made the careless mistake of referring to the 10^6 in the OP's title as scientific notation. I removed all references to scientific notation and correctly identified it as exponentiation, which is what this question is about, how to speak or write something to the power of something. You're saying it would be better to remove any reference to exponentiation or exponent for simplicity? Also, what point didn't I address? Should I replace all the negatives with minuses?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh I see what you mean in your comment. In my opinion I find it more understandable to say something like "one millionth of a billion" rather than "one in ten followed by 14 zeros". I don't know, the whole "with x zeros after it" doesn't help me conceptualise it as much as saying something like "this much of this much of this much" That's probably just how my brain prefers it. You may be right though, and a better answer may be just what you're suggesting. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Zebrafish In my opinion, by contrast, I prefer the matter-of-fact "one in ten to the 36" or "ten to the minus 36". This clearly specifies the exponent. A combo of words such as billionth or trillionth forces me to both wonder what they individually mean *and* add the exponents. And this case is simpler than many because the exponent's a multiple of 3. When it isn't, you have to deal with the trick that in e.g. "ten trillionths" the "ten" multiplies, whereas in "a ten-trillionth" it divides.

Comment: @Zebrafish: As a somewhat over-the-hill Brit, I grew up thinking a billion was a million times a million (and a trillion was what we might today call a "zillion" :) But I never really had any meaningful real-world referents for numbers of that magnitude, so billion and trillion effectively meant "big number" and "*really* big number". Then at some point I had to accept that a billion was 1000 times smaller than it used to be, which on the plus side made it "meaningful" it terms of national government spending. And now even "trillion" has real-world referents ($ value of Apple, Amazon,...).

Comment: ...I also had to code my own "5-byte integer" computer storage format back in the 90's, cos I was writing analysis software where I had to sum tens of millions of £s *to the penny*. But I don't even think in terms of billions or trillions when quantifying video storage capacity - which started off as hundreds of megabytes, but is now some relatively small number of gigabytes (stored on a drive holding some small number of terabytes). The *actual number of bytes* on any of the discs containing my video library still isn't really a "meaningful" number to me.

Comment: @Michael Harvey < 'We often say "ten to the minus thirty-six" for that amount where I come from (UK).'> +1 assuming this to be tongue poking through cheek. -36 if it's actually true.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct?
>
> > one millionth of a billionth of a trillionth of a second.
>
> I can write one 'undecillionth' of a second, […]

That is **not** correct.

In the "short scale" (now used almost universally in the English-speaking world), "undecillionth" has the value you want (10<sup>−36</sup>), but "one millionth of a billionth of a trillionth" does not: one millionth is 10<sup>−6</sup>, one billionth is 10<sup>−9</sup>, and one trillionth is 10<sup>−12</sup>, so one millionth of one billionth of one trillionth is 10<sup>−6−9−12</sup> = 10<sup>−27</sup>. So you should instead write "a trillionth of a trillionth of a trillionth".

In the "long scale" (formerly used in the UK, and still used in many non-English-speaking countries), "one millionth of a billionth of a trillionth" has the correct value (10<sup>−6−12−18</sup> = 10<sup>−36</sup>), but "undecillionth" does not (it's 10<sup>−66</sup>); rather, you would use "sextillionth". Furthermore, even though "one millionth of a billionth of a trillionth" is correct, it's unnecessarily long, because in the "long scale", a millionth of a billionth *is* a trillionth; so it would be more sensible to say "a trillionth of a trillionth" (10<sup>−18−18</sup> = 10<sup>−36</sup>). (That said, "a millionth of a billionth of a trillionth" may do a better job evoking the *connotation* of "really super super tiny", if you want more than just a neutral/factual/objective description.)

---

Zebrafish's answer correctly describes how you would read 10<sup>−36</sup> aloud; but I feel that this is a misleading answer to your question, because we would not normally write out "ten to the power of minus thirty-six" in prose. Rather, we would use either the mathematical notation, 10<sup>−36</sup>, or a prose phrasing along the lines of your suggestion (e.g. "a trillionth of a trillionth of a trillionth").

Comment: Zebrafish's answer uses "negative 36", not "minus 36", so it does not "correctly describe how you would read it aloud".

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think "negative thirty-six" is perfectly correct, albeit more formal and less common. (Zebrafish's answer mentions both.)